# Duration for Garbage Collection in Android Studio Profiler is 0

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I'm profiling my application using the included Profiler in Android Studio and I would like to measure the garbage collections, their durations and freed memory.

While the app is running, I can see the garbage collections happening but their duration is 0 and I'm not seeing something in the logcat at the approximate time the GC is occuring.
[image]

Could someone give me a hand?